# Advantage of chained `operator >>` over Variadic Template Function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following C++ code:

```
A a = ...;
B b = ...;
C c = ...;

cin >> a >> b >> c;
...
cout << a << b << c;
```

Now that we have C++11 variadic template functions (I think) it could have been implemented one of these ways:

```
cin.read(a,b,c);
cout.write(a,b,c);

read(cin,a,b,c);
write(cout,a,b,c);

cin(a,b,c);
cout(a,b,c);
```

Are there any advantages of the chained `<<` operator over these ways?  Put another way - Do you think if they had variadic template functions in the beginning they still would have used `operator <<` and `operator >>`?  If so, why?

Comment: I like `<<` and `>>` because they somehow remind me of a _stream_ ...

Comment: Less code bloat. Chaining doesn't generate any new code. Unrolling of variadic templates does.

Answer (score 5):

One of the most important aspects of iostreams is that it is *extensible*. You can add new types and all you need to do is provide an overloaded `<<` for writing and `>>` for reading.

You would need to provide a similar mechanism for your variadic version.

You would have to provide some global or namespace-scoped function name, which would be called by argument-dependent lookup by `istream::read` and `ostream::write`. The name of this function would need to be well-defined. But you won't find that function's name in `cin.read(a,b,c);` at all. Unless it's `read`, in which case you've got a number of potential name conflict problems.

This mechanism would be less immediately obvious than overloading `operator<<`. You would need to look up the docs to know what the name of the function to write an overload for is, while `operator<<` is right there in the statement: `cout << ...`.

Comment: +1. The overload potential is the most important advantage of this approach.

Comment: Couldn't you just overload the single parameter version?  And the variadic version uses that?

Comment: You can't overload `cin(a);`.

Comment: True but for some `f`, you could overload `f(cin,x)` and then have `f(cin,a,b,c)` call `f(cin,a)`, `f(cin,b)` and `f(cin,c)`. `f` could be one of `read`/`write`, `scan`/`print`, `get`/`put`, and so on.

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling: Yes, I mentioned that. And `read/write` are way too generic, as are `get/put`; an argument can be made for `scan/print` as well. And as I stated, it would be a lot less obvious what you function need to overload, whereas `<<` is right there in the statement.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Because the dispatch is bound to the type of the parameters, the first being a stream type, where would a naming conflict arise?  In much the same way as there is no conflict between arithmetic shift and the stream version of `<<`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `<<` being right there in the statement.  Whatever the function name was, it would be right there in the statement.

Comment: @Benjamin: The function you use internally does not *have* to be named the same as the variadic function you use externally. Whereas you can't get around the fact that `<<` is highly visible; the rules of C++ operator overloading tell you exactly what functions get called. You *know*, rather than suspect, what the name of the function you need to overload is.

Comment: @Andrew: "Because the dispatch is bound to the type of the parameters, the first being a stream type, where would a naming conflict arise?" Because it's entirely possible that someone has already written a global "read" function that takes a stream as its first parameter. It's a lot less likely that someone would overload `operator<<` to do the same and *not* be intending to use it like this.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You're begging the question. If `read(istream&, ...)` had of been in place from the beginning of iostream, it would be as unlikely someone would use `read(istream&, ...)` for something else as it is that they would use `operator>>(istream&, ...)` for something else today.